# how to set folder home page for outlook web access 2013

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, outlook-web-app

I have a folder created per mailbox in exchange server 2013. Once user clicks on  this folder, he is redirected to another virtual directory configured on another machine but its in same domain.

In outlook, i can achieve this by setting a folder home page with the actual address of the virtual directory

e.g. https://mailserver.mail.local/client/defaultframe.aspx

Is there any way to achieve this using Outlook Web Access 2013 (OWA)

I tried deploying an outlook app, but couldn't get the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can - OWA does not respect folder home page settings set in Outlook.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We use to support this till outlook 2010. Unfortunately same code doesn't work with exchange 2013 and outlook 2013